# In Bugsnax, how do you get the "Say Cheese!" trophy after reaching the point of no return?

Tags: achievements, bugsnax

Right before the point of no return at the end of Bugsnax, each Grumpus has returned to the Snaxburg. In order to get the "Say Cheese!" hidden trophy, I need to do the following:

> Scan a Grumpus after saucing them with cheese.

However, I am not able to open up my tool menu in Snaxburg to sauce them with cheese. How do I earn the trophy? Do I need to start over?

I ran through the point of no return once but you lose your tools and it doesn't seem like you're able to sauce a Grumpus and scan them.

Comment: I would have tagged this with a [bugsnax] tag, but I don't have privileges to create a tag.

Comment: Ill do it for ya!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to start over the game and you can still earn the trophy even if you played through the point of no return once.

Start the point of no return end sequence. As you are climbing up the mountain with the NPCs, you can quickly pull out your tools and sauce one of them with cheese and scan them. You will have to do this before entering the mountain doors. If you do miss it, you are able to play through the sequence again after completing it.

Answer (score -2):

You can go to frosted peak after completing the game. Eggabelle should still be there and cheese her!